# Windows python multiprocessing : nothing happened when running the function

Tags: python, windows, compilation, multiprocessing, pool

i have below code for **list excel file in folder**, and after **read** the file using panda,  doing some filldown/etc on each, **compile** all of the file into one dataframe

below is single thread version of the code, and its working :

```
Folder = "Folder Name"
StartRead = 2
num_cores = 2

DefaultPath = "C:\\Users\\"

path = DefaultPath + Folder
file_identifier = "*.xlsx"




def reader(filename):
    raw_read = pd.read_excel(filename,skiprows=StartRead)
    fixed_read = raw_read.fillna(method='ffill')
return fixed_read

def load_serial():
    dfs = pd.DataFrame()
    list_ = []
    file_list = glob2.glob(path + "\\*" + file_identifier)
    for f in file_list:
        df = reader(f)
        list_.append(df)
    dfs = pd.concat(list_) 
    return dfs

data = load_serial()
```

im trying to do the same in parallel, since the actual file to be compiled is around~2000 excel file.

But somehow doesnt show anything after running it  in jupyter with 10 test file, just like above :

```
import time
import glob2
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import os
import concurrent.futures

Folder = "Folder"
StartRead = 2
num_cores = 2

DefaultPath = "C:\\Users\\"

path = DefaultPath + Folder
file_identifier = "*.xlsx"




def reader(filename):
    raw_read = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=StartRead)
    fixed_read = raw_read.fillna(method='ffill')
    return fixed_read

def load_serial():
    dfs = pd.DataFrame()
    list_ = []
    file_list = glob2.glob(path + "\\*" + file_identifier)
    for f in file_list:
        df = reader(f)
        list_.append(df)
    dfs = pd.concat(list_) 
    return dfs



start1 = time.time()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list = glob2.glob(path + "\\*" + file_identifier)
    pool = mp.Pool(num_cores)
    list_of_results = pool.map_async(reader, file_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

end1 = time.time()
```

Did i miss something? Thank you

this is tested on my dual core notebook with 10 file
the actual run will be on my 32 core server running windows, with ~2000 excel file in each folder

Thank you

Edit:

Finally i have it run

First, function reader need to be on separate file

Then wrap the main function within if **name** == '**main**'

I've tested it on may main 32 core machine and its properly spool up all the core

Will put the fixed code tomorrow, im really sleepy right now...

Comment: `list_of_results = pool.map_async(reader, file_list)` don't you want to map `load_serial`?

Comment: Or, actually, some mix of the two functions. Currently you aren't building anything, you just read the excel, but you don't do anything with the data

Comment: @roganjosh yes im trying to spool up the core first. Basically what i done is to store it on a list object (so i got a list of dataframe which is a result of reader fn working on file_list list), and concat it using panda. Will post the code tomorrow - im really sleepy right now haha